# How to set UIImage frame

Tags: iphone, uiimage

How i can set the frame size of UIImage.

Comment: you can check this link [http://iphonedevelopertips.com/graphics/how-to-scale-an-image-using-an-objective-c-category.html](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/graphics/how-to-scale-an-image-using-an-objective-c-category.html)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can set the frame of the `UIImageView`:

```
UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

(and don't forget to `[imgView release];` somewhere)

Answer (score 6):

UIImage has no frame. It has only width and height. If you want to put it on your view you should create UIImageView

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12,12,123,123)];
imageView.image = image; // image - your UIImage
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i need to set the frame size of image not imageView, ok i will try some other way to workaround.

Comment: UIImage is object representing image, it's not view and therefore doesn't have frame. Do you want to resize image maybe?